# Unable to navigate backward using hardware key in a Universal App

Tags: windows-phone, win-universal-app

I navigate forward using `Frame.Navigate` but when I press the hardware back key on my phone I end up on the start screen and not the page I just visited.

What might be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason behind your problem is, you are creating a Blank Page. If you're creating a blank page, you should define what the app has to do when the back button is fired.

Better, consider adding "Basic page". It will have backstack by nature. If you are navigating from the `MainPage` to the `Basic Page` and when you pressed back button at the `Basic Page` it will back to the `MainPage`.

I hope this could solve your problem!

If you want to use `Blank Page` in your application, you need to use like this on your page where you wanna override back button:

add this in your header:

```
using Windows.Phone.UI.Input;
```

and then in your constructor:

```
HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
```

add this anywhere in your code:

```
void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
{
    HardwareButtons.BackPressed -= HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've probably forgotten to use the `NavigationHelper` included in the template of the universal app.

You should use it like this on every page:

```
NavigationHelper _navigationHelper;

public LoginPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    _navigationHelper = new NavigationHelper(this);
}
```